# Enumerated data type into an int type?

Tags: c, initialization, translate

I am quite new to C and I am given these instructions:

"translate the enumerated data type dfaState into an int
type; hence, the variable state should be an int variable. Additionally, map the enumeration values EE, OE, OO and EO to the integer constants 0, 1, 2, and 3, respectively."

And here is the code I am given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum dfaState { EE, OE, OO, EO };
enum dfaState state = EE;
char input;

int main(void)
{
    //main function here
}
```

How should I approach these instructions? I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int EE = 0;
int OE = 1;
int OO = 2;
int EO = 3;
int state;
char input;

int main(void)
```

but I am getting errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *but I am getting errors* Are you seeing errors at compile time, at run time? It will be good to see a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RSahu they are compile errors.

Comment: @flarp you might want to post them...

Comment: Why do you rewrite the given code? The given code already satisfies the assignment: It has four enumerated constants with the values 0, 1, 2, and 3 respectively. In C, `enum` values are constant integer values. You can even assign values not in the enumeration to `state` (and you should take care not to).

Answer (score 0):

From the C11 standard:

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers**
>
> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer
>   type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
>   implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the
>   values of all the members of the enumeration.

That means in C a enum underlying type is already an integral type: your code will already do what it's supposed to do: you can make it more explicit to use the values 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum dfaState {
  EE = 0,
  OE = 1,
  OO = 2,
  EO = 3
};
enum dfaState state = EE;

int main(void) {
  printf("dfaState %d\n", state); // will print "0"
  return 0;
}
```